# How to use EventEmitter(onClose) of the sidenav

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I want to check when my

```
<md-sidenav>
```

is getting closed. 
Is there a way to use the EventEmitter onClose of my sidenav object to check that?
and can you give me an example?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is possible in 2 different ways - via the template, and within the component code itself.

Assuming an HTML template such as the following:

```html
<md-sidenav-container>
  <md-sidenav #mySidenav (close)="onClose()" mode="side">
    This is sidenav content
  </md-sidenav>
  <button md-raised-button (click)="mySidenav.toggle()">Toggle Sidenav</button>
</md-sidenav-container>
```

In your component you can have something like this:

```js
import { AfterViewInit, Component, OnDestroy, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MdSidenav } from '@angular/material'
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('mySidenav')
  sidenav: MdSidenav;

  subscription: Subscription;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.subscription = this.sidenav.onClose.subscribe(() =>
      console.log("Closed event from observable"));
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  onClose(): void {
    console.log("Closed event from template");
  }

}
```

Technique 1 is to use an event binding. This is the `(close)="onClose()"` section of the template. Whenever the close event is fired by the sidenav, the code specified in the quotes (i.e. `onClose()`) is run. In this scenario, the method `onClose()` (which is defined in the component code) is called, and prints some text to the console. You can find out more about this technique in the [Event Bindings section of the angular documentation.](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#event-binding)

Technique 2 is to subscribe to the event in the component code itself. In this technique we export the sidenav as the variable `mySidenav`. This is the `#mySidenav` section of the template. In the component code we can get a reference to the sidenav by using the `@ViewChild('mySidenav')` annotation. When our component is initialised, we can gain access to the sidenav and hence run some code whenever the close event is fired. In this scenario, we use the `subscribe()` method of the `Observable` interface. It's important to unsubscribe from the subscription when the compoenent is destroyed to prevent memory leaks, hence the `unsubscribe()` call in `ngOnDestroy()`. You can find out more about observables in the [Observables section of the rxjs documentation](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/subscribe.md).

Comment: Neither is working for me when I close the sidenav by clicking the outside the panel

Comment: Typo in the sidenav declaration... should say (closed) not (close)

Comment: Apparently this changed in 5.0.0-rc.0 according to the release notes - https://github.com/angular/components/blob/5.0.0-rc0/CHANGELOG.md#deprecations

Answer (score 3):

Its actually very simple as below

HTML

```
<md-sidenav-container class="example-container">
  <md-sidenav #sidenav class="example-sidenav" (close)="onClose()" >
    Jolly good!
  </md-sidenav>

  <div class="example-sidenav-content">
    <button md-button (click)="sidenav.open()">
      Open sidenav
    </button>
  </div>

</md-sidenav-container>
```

Handling the method in Component Class as

```
onClose(){
    window.alert('closed the side nav bar');

  }
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/Gh1Yf2tJQ4Z0GG9aAeUm?p=preview)